# Run GWT locally in release mode?

Tags: gwt

Is there any way to run GWT in "release" mode locally? I'm developing a project using canvas, and it's so painfully slow that I can't really be productive. In release mode the performance is fine. Obviously I'd lose all the benefits of debug mode, but in this case it's taking too long to work,

Thanks

----------------- Edit -----------------

By "release" mode I mean "production" mode. Running "locally" means I right-click the project in eclipse, then choose Run As -> Web Application. Then I can navigate a browser to "http://127.0.0.1:8888/myproject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997" to view. It's here that the canvas code runs way too slow to be productive.

Again, it runs fine in "production" mode (right-click the app, google -> deploy to app engine). When I hit the live url (http://myproject.appspot.com), the canvas code runs nice and fast.

So in "local" mode, every time I make a change to my source and refresh the browser, the changes are immediately available. But for this case, could I run production mode locally instead?

Thanks again

Comment: Do you mean `production` mode ? What do you mean by `locally` ? Please give us more information. What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Hi yes more info above, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need to deploy to app engine.

Simply, *right-click the project in eclipse, then choose Run As -> Web Application*

Then,

- instead of navigating to:
  '**http://127.0.0.1:8888/myproject.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997**'
- Just go to: '**http://127.0.0.1:8888/myproject.html**'

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I'm looking for - just a way to run locally with the code compiled to javascript. So that works, but when I make a change in the java code, the changes aren't reflected in the second url you listed after a browser refresh. I need to do Google -> GWT Compile, then a browser refresh. Is that expected?

Comment: @user291701 No you just need to reRun the Web Application

Comment: If i try this i get the message: "GWT module 'yourmodule' may need to (re)compiled" ...?

Comment: @eftokay83 This is a different issue but try cleaning your project before running it

Comment: Already tried it. Maybe the problem is elsewhere: My setup is maven / eclipse / gwt ( with needed eclipse plugins for the setup )

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's not normal that your `Developper` mode runs slow. Maybe you should take a look to find why it's slow.

To run in `Production` mode, you can locally :

1. Compile and package your application
2. Deploy it to a local server such as `Tomcat`

You should find more information here  :

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/2.4/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging?hl=fr

Comment: Yes specifically canvas operations are extremely slow. This is the main problem.